# Хочу научиться работать с Python многопрофильно, писать бэк сайтов, делать ботов

Tags: python

Я только начал погружаться в мир программирования и пока не знаю с чего начать, может мой выбор языка был необоснованным, можете предложить варианты лучше, если есть какие-нибудь советы с чего начать, как учиться, по чем учиться, буду признателен.

А вот для развлекухи код который я писал с помощью ChatGPT, не обращайте внимание на то, как написан код, знаю что крайне ужасно, я просто его не редактировал, а копи пастил и правил понемногу, пока сам ещё могу его понимать, через неделю наверное не смогу))

Это ТГ бот для магазина свечей (Но я пока не до конца все функции реализовал):
<положите код сюда>

Ссылка с архивом, потому что там БД и без неё не запустится

Comment: Минимальные требования Python FastAPI сервера - 4 ГБ RAM, минимальные требования php-cgi процесса 10 МБ, исходя из чего можно ориентироваться на выбор бюджета хостинга.

Comment: Вопрос хоть и похож на иску сственный, но зря минусуют. Человек разобраться без человечных ответов не сможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рад, что ты решил начать изучать программирование. Я бы рекомендовал начать с изучения основ программирования на любом языке, который тебе более интересен. Сейчас очень много ресурсов для изучения, начиная от бесплатных курсов на YouTube и Codecademy, заканчивая платными онлайн-курсами и университетскими программами. Многие ресурсы также предлагают углубленное изучение конкретных языков программирования.

Относительно выбора языка программирования, я бы посоветовал выбрать язык, который более всего подходит для решения задач, которые тебе интересны. Например, если тебе интересно веб-программирование, то JavaScript и Python могут быть хорошими вариантами. Если тебе интересны научные вычисления или машинное обучение, то Python может быть лучшим выбором. Если тебе интересны низкоуровневые операции и системное программирование, то C++ может быть более подходящим выбором.

Относительно твоего кода, важно помнить, что практика является важной частью процесса обучения программированию. Я бы порекомендовал начать с изучения основ языка программирования, пробовать писать свои программы и решать задачи. Постепенно ты будешь замечать, как твой код становится более читаемым и эффективным.

Успехов в изучении программирования!

Comment: Неожиданно так тепло отнеслись к моим начинаниям, спасибо большое за советы, очень приятно :)

Comment: В последнее время, когда я вижу тут все больше таких вопросов вместе с отсылками к ChatGPT, мне все чаще кажется, что  учиться программировать уже поздно. Еще несколько лет и  такие "программисты" станут абсолютно не нужны.

Comment: может chatGPT натравить, чтобы он сам отвечал на вопросы. тогда и мы не нужны будем))

Comment: Ну когда не знаешь с чего начать, я считаю неплохой способ понять, как и что работает с объяснениями от chat gpt, тем более на собственном проекте, если это можно так назвать

Comment: Я же не просто прошу его напиши мне бота, чтобы он умел то и это. 
Я спрашиваю как создавать функции, работать с БД и т.п..

Comment: А просто копи пастнуть код, каждый может

Comment: @АртёмКазьменко все делаете правильно. чат - ваш личный ментор

Comment: @SeniorPomidor  *"может chatGPT натравить, чтобы он сам отвечал на вопросы. тогда и мы не нужны будем"* --- ты, возможно, удивишься, но это уже во всю делают. Даже дошло до того, что временно этот чатгпт на стаке объявлен вне закона.... Потому что часто ответы от него либо небольшая мешанина, либо вода, и поэтому пока от него больше вред, чем польза...но иногда проскальзывает что-то путное, если подредачить.... Так что уже это происходит

Comment: Да, прежде всего нужно исходить из стоящей задачи. На SQL не очень удобно писать графические интерфейсы, а на Pascal писать highload.

Comment: @АртёмКазьменко, сейчас не столько важно, что за язык или что за технология перед тобой, сколько то, чтобы близкое окружение понимало и принимало твоё увлечение или хотя бы не мешало, а также, чтобы было достаточно свободного времени не во вред себе, и была доступна помощь в случае трудностей, а главное - не пропал интерес к занятиям, поэтому двигайтесь поступательно и равномерно.

Answer (score -1):

Лучше начать с основ алгоритмов и структур данных. Материалов по ним на русском языке сейчас много. Важно прийти к пониманию, зачем они вообще нужны в мире программирования. Для этого нужно выбрать для старта один язык программирования, профилировщик и отладчик к нему. Первое время все базовые функции лучше реализовывать самостоятельно, параллельно осваивая алгоритмы и применяя подходящие структуры данных. Важно помнить, что оптимизация строится на основе бизнес-потребностей и бывает по сложности алгоритма во времени исполнения (циклах процессора) и объёмам используемой памяти, а также нужно ориентироваться на конечную стоимость и сроки разработки и эксплуатации приложения - рано или поздно Вы от него либо откажетесь, либо модернизируете. Постепенно придёт понимание, что язык реализации приложения - вещь во многом индивидуальных предпочтений и вторичная. И да, не выбрасывайте деньги на макулатуру.

Comment: Не согласен. Лучше начать кодить, а алгоритмы не получится применять без знания языка

Comment: А что кодить без алгоритмов будем?

Comment: Да хоть сетевые крестики нолики через телеграм... Какой там алгоритм нужен? Сортировка пузырьков?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, раз начал с Python, то наверное буду пробовать себя в нём

Comment: Как доказано наукой, любая программа может быть представлена комбинацией алгоритмов последовательности, ветвления и цикла. Для начала рекомендую Вам пройти бесплатные курсы на русском языке онлайн с сертификатом по Python тут: https://stepik.org/catalog/search?cert=true&free=true&lang=ru&q=Python

Comment: @Грузчик если пишите "доказано наукой", то приводите ссылки на доказательства. Любая программа - это реализация какого-то алгоритма, но для написания многих программ не обязательно знать как реализуются алгоритмы типа сортировки или оптимизированного поиска.

Comment: Ссылка есть в книге "Чистая архитектура". Для удовлетворения современным бизнес-требованиям - обязательно.

Comment: Нет там никаких ссылок, это ты что-то напридумывал))  А вот слова @insolor вполне верны. И вот подтверждение его слов есть хотя бы банальное упоминание того, что в книге пишут в стиле *"Например, представьте, что функции calculatePay() и reportHours() используют общий алгоритм расчета не сверхурочных часов"*.... то есть всякая программа есть некий алгоритм... А вот твоих слов там нет. Какая-то научная доказанность там отсутствует и хоть какое-то упоминание о "изучите такие-то алгоритмы, это самое важное в жизни разработчика"

Comment: Значит, есть в книге Дейтелов по Си.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8